# Suppose that $Q$ is an orthogonal matrix and $\bar{Q}$ is the first $j$-columns. Geometrically what is $\bar{Q}\bar{Q}^T$?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, statistics

The question comes from PCA. What PCA does is that we represent an observation with a new basis $\tilde{Q} = \{q_1, \dots, q_k\}$, then we drop some dimensions in this new basis. In other words, we take $Q^Tx$ then we take only the first $j$ (where $j \leq k$) components of $Q^Tx$. Can also be seen as taking a hyperplane spanned by the first $j$ components of the standard basis, rotate this hyperplane and $x$, then project the rotated $x$ into this rotated hyperplane.

Now, there is something called an orthogonal distance $\text{OD}$. In words, this was described as the distance between the rotated observation and the (rotated, projected) observation. To me, this can simply be written as $\text{OD}(x) = \sqrt{\sum_{i=j+1}^{k}\langle Q^Tx,q_i\rangle}$.

However, let $\bar{Q} = [q_1, \dots, q_j]$. Let $\hat{x} := \bar{Q}\bar{Q}^Tx$ be the 'predicted' values. In my notes, the $\text{OD}(x):= ||x - \hat{x}||$. I can't figure out why that is. **For any orthogonal $Q$ and any vector $x$, geometrically what is $\bar{Q}\bar{Q}^Tx$?**

In the context of PCA though, my guess for the definition would be: Let $y = Q^Tx$, and $\bar{y} = \bar{Q}^Tx$. Now, $\hat{x}=\bar{Q}\bar{y}$. Let us consider a single co-ordinate $x_i$. We know that $\sum_{s=1}^k Q_{is} y_s = x_i$, but notice that $\hat{x_i}=\sum_{s=1}^j Q_{is} y_s$. That is, the only difference between $x_i$ and predicted $\hat{x}_i$ is actually just $\sum_{s=j+1}^k Q_{is} y_s$. In the context of PCA, these $y_s$ have small(-est variation, hence dropped) values, thus the reconstruction $\hat{x}$ should be close to $x$ since the differences $\sum_{s=j+1}^k Q_{is} y_s$ are also small.

I haven't tried to check whether the two expressions are actually the same (they might be), but my main question is about the geometrical aspect, as that is what's bothering me right now.

Comment: In the fourth paragraph, I can understand why such a metric would be interesting, but I don't see why is it called 'orthogonal' distance.

Comment: It's a projection of $x$ into the span of $\bar Q$. The first multiply $\bar Q^T x$ gives you $x$ in that reduced coordinate system. The second multiply brings you back into the same space as $x$, but now you've removed any other components. You could also think of this as $QZQ^T x$ where $Z$ is a diagonal of $1$'s and $0$'s that keeps only the terms that $\bar Q$ has

Comment: @AlexK makes total sense!